# How to use/enable LINQ combined with custom serializer? (MONGODB C#)

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, serialization

I have a few entities that have custom serializers.

```
public class EntitySerializer : BsonBaseSerializer, IBsonIdProvider
{
   public override object Deserialize(MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options){
      ...
      bsonReader.ReadName(); // _id
      ObjectId id = bsonReader.ReadObjectId();
      ...
}
public override void Serialize(MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
{
     ...
     bsonWriter.WriteObjectId("_id", ent.Id);
     ...
    }
}

....

BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(Entity), new EntitySerializer());
```

Now I would like to query this entity through LINQ.

```
GetEntityCollection().AsQueryable<Entity>().Where(d=>d.Id==new ObjectId("51b8939d3f92b82db4ad1db0"))
```

This returns me the following error

```
NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: d.Id.
```

This behavior does not occur when not using a custom serializer so I am guessing I forgot or missed something. Searching the internet did not yield me anything that I could resolve the error with. Could someone please show me what I am missing?

---

Solution given at Google Groups: implement IBsonDocumentSerializer.

Comment: Is there an `Id` property? Does the query work if you don't use the strongly typed methods? `where("_id", ....)`

Comment: Id property is available (and compiles)
The query works without LINQ (e.g. GetEntityCollection().FindAs<Entity>(Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId("51b8939d3f92b82db4ad1db0"))))
I don't see an extension method to do a .Where without lambda...

Comment: Why are you trying to use the LINQ extensions? The results aren't more efficient.

Comment: There isn't a `where`, the comment was an early morning from my iPad comment which you translated successfully into what I'd meant. :)

Comment: LINQ extensions allow me (1) to use type safe queries and (2) to abstract the actual database logic away in it's own library (provider model). I rather not see any MongoDB code in the business logic.

Comment: The MongoDB driver behavior also seems correct. When registering the custom serializer I also should somehow tell it how to map the fields to my business objects... I just do not know how to make this mapping happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you are serializing to a document, your custom serializer needs to implement IBsonDocumentSerializer.  IF it is serializing to an array, it needs to implement IBsonArraySerializer.  These interfaces allow Linq to work with custom classes.

Comment: you implement these interfaces on the serialiser?

Comment: Yes.  Implement these on the custom IBsonSerializer.  You probably won't implement both of them, just the one that applies.

Comment: What do you use in the IBsonSerializationOption argument of the ..Info ctor?

Comment: e.g. `public BsonSerializationInfo GetMemberSerializationInfo(string memberName)
        {
            return new BsonSerializationInfo(memberName, this, typeof(string), null);
        }` where the null is?